# How can I sandbox some external Javascript without using iframes?

Tags: javascript, web, sandbox

I want to add some external script to a webpage. This scripts are pluggins wich should only be able to acces and modify the part of the dom they are assign too. This scripts will be developed by eternals developers and I will not be able to control them all by hand.

I know I can easily handle this problems by creating an iframe for each pluggins to run in. Unfortunately this solution is really slow on mobile devices.

How can I sandbox this scrips without using an iframe? (I can also do some work server side)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could do what [Facebook did](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/) and made their version of the language.

Comment: It could be a way. They give it recently, I'm wondering why...

Comment: You can run untrusted scripts in Web Workers and exchange messages with them to update UI (DOM) from your core script.